# How to difference 2 rows in dataframe when condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My dataframe:

| f1 | f2 | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 5 | 7 | 0 |
| 9 | 11 | 0 |
| 4 | 9 | 1 |
| 9 | 16 | 1 |
| 16 | 25 | 0 |

I want to get f1-f2, when f1 condition is the first 1 and f2 condition is the last 0. For example, in the first 2 rows, I want to get 2-3=-1. The next example would be 4-25=-21. I cant do a fixed subtraction by just shifting the entire f2 column by 2 because the distance between 1 and 0 can vary as it did in the dataframe.

Comment: so in the updated example the first value is still 2-3? not 2-11?

Comment: @mozway yes still 2-3. I misspoke and said first 1 and last 0 when I should have said first 1 and first 0

Comment: then you should use the (now deleted) alternative grouping strategy of @ScottBoston `group = df['Condition'].eq(0)[::-1].cumsum()` and `groupby(group, as_index=False, sort=False)` the rest identical to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can make groups when there is a transition from 0 to 1, then take the first f1 and last f2, use that to compute f1 - f2.

With this approach, the first value in a group is necessarily 1 and the last 0, (except eventually for the very first row if 0 and last one if 1, but how should it be handled in this case?)

```
group = df['Condition'].diff().eq(1).cumsum()
(df
 .groupby(group)
 .agg({'f1': 'first', 'f2': 'last'})
 .eval('f1-f2')
)
```

variant:

```
group = df['Condition'].diff().eq(1).cumsum()
(df
 .groupby(group)
 .apply(lambda d: d['f1'].iloc[0]-d['f2'].iloc[-1])
)
```

output:

```
Condition
0    -1
1   -21
dtype: int64
```